# Error on careers search page

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When I click the search tab after managing my job listing I get:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=%2Femployer%2Fjobs%2F51133%

We do not have the opportunity to search for candidates due to this bug.  Please let us know why this is happening.  Sorry folks I am becoming quite frustrated with the careers site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry about that -- this is a bug introduced by the new permission system. I've fixed the issue so you should be able to see the search page now.

Note, however, that you still won't be able to contact candidates or see full results unless you also purchase a candidate search subscription (job listings do not come with a search subscription).